# importing a package on mac

Tags: java, macos, package

hey guys having this really simple problem but cant seem to figure out have to import this package called `it` but i have no idea where to put the actual folder on the mac, keeps on giving an error `package does not exist`, this is a really stupid question, but really have no idea what to do

here is the code (java) :

```
import it.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class pyramidColour
{           
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
     int col1 = (int)(Math.random()*255+1);
     int col2 = (int)(Math.random()*255+1);
     int col3 = (int)(Math.random()*255+1);

     Color newCol = new Color (col1, col2, col3);

     Gogga bug= new Gogga();//creating the gogga
     Gogga(1,8);

     for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i ++)//loop for going up 
     {
        bug.move();
        bug.turnRight();
        bug.move();
        bug.turnLeft();
     }

     bug.setDirection(bug.DOWN);

     for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i ++)//loop for going down
     {         
        bug.move();
        bug.turnLeft();
        bug.move();
        bug.turnRight();         
     }

     bug.move();
     bug.turnRight();

     for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i ++)//loop for base of pyramid
     {
        bug.move();
     }         
  }
}
```

The next part of the project is putting the loops into a method, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your folder structure und how do you try to compile/run the code? Maby your `CLASS_PATH` has to be changed?

Comment: which IDE you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the classpath of the package in the java command :

```
java -cp .;<path to the it classes> pyramidColour
```

`.` before `;` stand for current directory, where pyramidColour class is stored.

Edit : on Mac the delimiter is not `;` but `:` (thanks Jesper)

If you are using an IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans) you can simply add the library in the project properties.

Comment: On the Mac it should be `:` instead of `;`.

Comment: the " it " folder is on my desktop  ( sorry guys new to java)

Comment: @user1453779 So replace `<path to the it classes>` with the absolute path of your desktop

Comment: pyramidColour.java:3: class, interface, or enum expected
   java -cp .:Desktop/it pyramidColour
   ^

Comment: @user1453779 I don't know jgrasp, but you can use the commant line above using the path of your class pyramidColour (the .class file not the .java) and the path of the it folder.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example on jGrasp

```
import java.awt.*;
import it.*;
public class DiscoSquares
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int red, green, blue;
        Color col = new Color(255, 0, 0);
      Gogga.setGridSize(17, 17);
        Gogga bug = new Gogga();
      bug.setTrailWidth(150);
        for (int dir = 1; dir <=4; dir++)
        {
            bug.setDirection (dir);
            for(int sides=1;sides<=4;sides++)
            {
                for(int length=1;length<=5;length++)
                {
                    bug.move();
                }
                bug.turnLeft();
            }
            if(dir==4)
                dir = 0;
         red = (int)(Math.random()*255+1);
            green = (int)(Math.random()*255+1);
            blue = (int)(Math.random()*255+1);
            col = new Color(red, green, blue);
            bug.setColor(col);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Packages are like folders, so you would have to put those packages in the same parent folder as that of the code which imports it. So it should be like

```
<it> folder
    programs
<another package> folder
    pyramidColor
```

This [article](http://suite101.com/article/how-to-create-a-java-package-a91474) should help you out.

Comment: java -cp .:Desktop/it pyramidColour